# Homeomorphic punctured planes

Tags: general-topology

I've been trying to answer the following question, but I don't know what topological property I should be looking at.

For each natural number $n$ we consider a space $X_n$ that is obtained by removing $n$ distinct points from $R^2$. We consider the 1-point compactification $X_n^+$ and we denote by $∞_n ∈ X_n^+$ the point at infinity (so that $X^+_n = X_n ∪ ∞_n$). Show that if $X_n$ and $X_m$ are homeomorphic, then $n = m$.

My approach so far has been to assume that $n≠m$ and then trying to find a difference in topological properties between $X_n$ and $X_m$. The most obvious one to me was showing that they are homeomorphic to a sphere with $n+1$ and $m+1$ missing points respectively and that these spheres are not homeomorphic to each other. Is this a correct approach and if it is, how would i go about proving that these punctured spheres are not homeomorphic?

Comment: If you want to follow the route suggested by the question, look at the connectedness properties of deleted neighbourhoods of the points at infinity.

Answer (score 0):

With an algebraic approach...

You note that if $n\neq m$ then the foundamental groups are different, but if $X_n^+ , X_m^+$ are homeomorphic the the foundamental groups are isomorphic.